# How to mkdir in if statement

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, mkdir

I'm new to coding and trying to teach myself. I was wondering why I keep getting "notcoolbeans" instead of creating the directory?

```
!/bin/sh
if [ $mkdir /Users/Matt/Desktop/Yaya = 1 ];
then
     echo "theres beans"
else
     echo "notcoolbeans"
fi
```

The directory does not already exist. I am trying to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct implementation would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if mkdir /Users/Matt/Desktop/Yaya; then
  echo "theres beans"
else
  echo "notcoolbeans"
fi
```

Items of note:

- A valid shebang starts with `#!`, not `!`. (BTW, consider `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh` instead of `#!/bin/sh` if you want a more full-featured scripting language).
- `[ ]` **is not part of the `if` statement**. It's a command that runs tests and sets exit status on output, but if you want to test the exit status of a different command, there's no call to use it.
- `$mkdir` is trying to expand a variable named `mkdir`. No such variable can be reasonably expected to exist in a new shell; if it's empty, then the result is `[ /Users/Matt/Desktop/Yaya = 1 ]`. `"/Users/Matt/Desktop/Yaya"` and `"1"` are not identical strings, so this always fails.